# Make multiple lightboxes (facebox) execute one after each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebox

I have a php application that sometimes creates two lightboxes on the same page - the result is the last one to be called is the only one shown. How might I ensure that they show one after anohter?

I call a facebox at the bottom of the page like so:

```
jQuery.facebox('blah');
```

Currently multiple facebox's are called like so:

```
jQuery.facebox('blah');jQuery.facebox('blah2');
```

But only blah2 will ever show.

I need to wait for 'blah' to close before calling 'blah2'...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a close event available (I've never used the facebox plugin) I would do something like this:

```
jQuery.facebox('blah'); 
jQuery.one('faceboxClose', function () { jQuery.facebox('blah2'); });
```

Comment: Thanks gddc This looks like it would work, but I would need it to be expandable, say if I had three lightboxes...